# Flask. Обработка без GET запроса

Tags: flask, gps, навигация

Имеется GPS-трекер, который отправляет свои данные на прописанный в настройках сервер (мой IP:PORT). Данные приходят в формате строки: `#L#2.0;86******7449285;NA;69BB`

Как при помощи Flask (или другого инструмента) поймать эту строку и обработать? Flask отлавливает только запросы с браузера (`/, /help` и т.п.). Данные не соответствует такому формату.

Мою строку с трекера Flask распознает как плохой запрос:

`192.168.18.1 - - [19/Oct/2022 13:37:44] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('#L#2.0;86*****57449285;NA;69BB')`
`192.168.18.1 - - [19/Oct/2022 13:37:44] "#L#2.0;86*****57449285;NA;69BB" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST`

Подскажите метод Flask или другой инструмент для Python, который позволит получать данные со входа на сервер

Answer (score 0):

Не разобрался как реализовать при помощи Flask, но это легко сделать при помощи socket.
Предварительная подготовка:

1. Настройка GPS трекера на отправку данных на сервер.
   Прописываем IP адрес (или домен) сервера и номер порта.
2. На роутере с белым, статичным IP адресом делаем проброс указанного в трекере порта на локальный IP адрес вашего компьютера/сервера.
3. В python используем встроенную библиотеку socket. Поднимаем на ней сервер (тестовый)

   ```
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # создает объект сокета
    server.bind((host, port))           # Работа в качестве сервера
    server.listen(1)                    # Кол-во ожидаемых соединений
    conn, addr = server.accept()        # Произведено подключение
    print(f'Connect to {addr}.')
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1460)          # 1460 - размер пакета. (см. документацию на прибор)
        if data:                        # Если есть данные
            print(data)                 # Выводим
            conn.sendall(b'#AL#1\r\n')  # Ответ для авторизации устройства (см. документацию на прибор)
   ```

Что происходит?
Данные отправляются с GPS-трекера Умка310, по протоколу Wialon 2.0 на роутер с белым, статичным IP адресом, там пробрасываются на ваш компьютер с запущенным сервером.
на сервер поступает первичный пакет для "рукопожатия".
В ответ на первичный пакет отвечаем командой `b'#AL#1\r\n'` (см. документацию на прибор)
После авторизации, устройство пришлет вам пакеты с информацией.
Вам нужно их разобрать